# Set value in random ViewController (random segue)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have 12 ViewControllers. My code gives a random segue to one of these ViewControllers (1-12)

```
let segues = ["View1", "View2", "View3", "View4", "View5", "View6", "View7", "View8", "View9", "View10", "View11", "View12"]
    let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(segues.count)))
    let segueName = segues[index]
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segueName, sender: self)
```

.

Now, I want to change a variable in the random ViewController that has been chosen (`var firstSegue = false`) but I can't figure out how?

.

Could someone change this into something that will work?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
    destinationVC.firstSegue = true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make a protocol with the `firstSegue` property and extend that to all of your view controllers.  Then use `as? TheProtocolYouMade` instead of `as UIViewController`

Or use a common sub-class.

EDIT: sample code

> Make a protocol with the `firstSegue` property

```
protocol P {
    var firstSegue: Bool { get set }
}
```

> extend that to all of your view controllers.

```
extension YOURViewController1: P {
}
```

It is assumed that YOURViewController1 has a `var firstSegue: Bool` in it.  Now that property is how YOURViewController1 conforms to protocol P.  Do this for all view controllers that have that property.

Now you can write this code

```
if let asP = segue.destinationViewController as? P {
   // you can access asP.firstSegue here
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example for a protocol with the `firstSegue`? I can't understand exactly how to put it in code but I think you've got the right answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As this controller has property that's not from standard UIViewController, than it's some custom controller, so you can cast it and than fill this value. As well you can use KVC - which is not really safe solution.